# How to remove elements from JSON using Python

Tags: python

I receive the following data from an API request, I would like to be able to search the data and select the ID where Name = "Steve" (for instance 3 in the example below)

The data returned from the API always has a different number of elements in, and the location of 'Steve' can be in a different part of the returned string. The ID will also change.

```
(Getdata){
   header = 
     (APIResponseHeader){
     sessionToken = "xxxx"
        }
   Items[] = 
   (Summary){
     Id = 1
     Name = "John"
     TypeId = 1
   },
   (Summary){
     Id = 2
     Name = "Jack"
     TypeId = 1
   },
   (Summary){
     Id = 3
     Name = "Steve"
     TypeId = 1

   },
 }
```

I think the format of the data is JSON(?) and I'm not sure how to convert, and then search it, if this is at all possible..?

Comment: That's not JSON john.

Comment: That is definitely not JSON.

Comment: Any idea what it could be then..?

Comment: Maybe this API has downloadable client for python? If not, you should write your own parser.